# Python language is not in a dropdown list in vscode when creating new azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I was able to create Azure function app in vscode.

[image]

Next, I am trying to create a new project using `Shift + Control + P` (cant find any other way)

[image]

Next, I dont see the option to select python language. I only see `.NetCore`

[image]

So how can I make sure I create project using python? Why python is not in a drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

***Can you please make sure that you have python pre installed if yes try deleting and reinstalling the extension because for me it is asking for language before going to runtime, when i try to reproduce i get it:***

[image]

***Then i get :***

[image]

***So the extensions i have are:***

[image]